# Why does ASP.NET change session when Safari requests file through ASHX handler?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, safari

Although Safari 5.1.7 for Windows is no longer supported by Apple, I am working on a web site that is required to be compatible with that browser. When the aspx page is served, I set a Session variable (InProc) in the PageLoad method. In the page, there are several image and video elements whose sources are of the form "/ContentHandler.ashx?k=something&z=somethingelse". The class definition starts with:

```
public class ContentHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```

When the request comes in for one of these files to the ProcessRequest method in ContentHandler.ashx, the context.Session is non-null, but the SessionID is completely different from what it was during the page load, and (therefore) the session variable I had set in the aspx PageLoad method is not present.

The mechanism works just fine in IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera - the session doesn't change and the session variable I set during page load is present and accounted for. Safari is the only one that is somehow causing a change of session when it requests one of these files through ContentHandler.ashx.  Cookies are enabled in Safari, but my application doesn't explicitly use cookies.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?  I can probably work around it by explicitly using a cookie, but wanted to avoid using cookies if I don't have to.

Edit (additional details): The session id is stored automatically in an HttpOnly cookie named ASP.NET_SessionId. It does not appear in the query string. The issue is that, in Safari, that session ID is different when I get to the ashx handler, but in all the other browsers, the session ID is identical to the session ID where I set the session variable in the aspx page load method. The URL of the aspx page itself and the URLs of the individual images and videos are identical across all browsers. All browsers have cookies enabled.

Yet more details: I added a Global.asax file and placed some do-nothing code in the Session_Start method. Session_Start is called at the beginning as expected, but what I'm also seeing is that, after the aspx Page_Load has executed, Session_Start is called again before the request for the first image file shows up in the ashx handler. So, a new session is starting between the aspx Page_Load and the first individual file request to ashx. This second session is initiated only on Safari.

Yet still more details: I ran across a discussion about how Safari "forgets" session variables when it thinks it's dealing with a 3rd party cookie. So, I set the browser to accept all cookies (including 3rd party cookies), and the problem persists...by the time we get to the ashx handler, the session ID has already been changed.

Thanks.

Comment: "My application does use cookies" did you mean to say that it *doesn't* use cookies? In which case, you're probably wrong. By default Session uses a cookie to associate the user to a particular session. Unless you turned that off, in which case it uses the query string (which is insecure).

Comment: I doubt this is the case as it is only happening in Safari, but is there any difference in the URL when calling the handler (protocol, hostname or port)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "doesn't use cookies," in that I don't explicitly use cookies, but you're right that the session id is stored automatically in an HttpOnly cookie named ASP.NET_SessionId. It does not appear in the query string. The issue is that, in Safari, that session ID is different when I get to the ashx handler, but in all the other browsers, the session ID is identical to the session ID where I set the session variable in the aspx page load method.

Comment: The URL of the aspx page itself and the URLs of the individual images and videos are identical across all browsers. The only browser where the session ID is different between the aspx page and the ashx handler is Safari.  In all other browsers, I see the original session ID when I get to the ashx handler.  All browsers have cookies enabled.

Comment: I know this is more than three years old, but I'm wondering if you ever resolved this issue, and if so, how. My application is also showing different behavior for HttpHandlers when using Safari vs. other browsers.

Comment: No, it was never resolved. I just worked around the Safari session behavior by using a cookie. Not elegant, but it got the job done. Of course, at this point, the site doesn't have to be Safari compatible anymore, so I haven't looked back.